# Why R.java is not imported automatically in my IDE?

Tags: android

In my new project I always have to import:

```
import com.abc.R;
```

or the problem: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" appears.

But in my other project I don't have to do that.
What is the difference and is there any problem?

Comment: what's the problem importing it?

Comment: i believe you are linking another android project which contains R.java. So the compiler is not able to automatically resolve which R you are referencing. try "ctrl+shift+o" and see.

Comment: I hope it is no problem, if there is none i can import it but I don't know why I don't have to import it in the other project.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you have an error in your xml `layout` and then you try to clean the project, you get this error.
Try to build the project, if it doesn't work, start a new one and copy the contents. Now that should work.

Comment: no I know this problem you explained but for me now it is something different.

Answer (score 0):

**In general, to make it work:**

1. use the Ctrl + Shift + O command to "Organize Imports" and generate
   any missing import statements. Sometimes this would generate the
   incorrect import statement which would hide the R.java class that is
   automatically generated when you build.
2. R is a generated class. If you are using the Android Development
   Tools (ADT) it is generated whenever the project is built. You may
   have 'Build Automatically' turned off. Turn it on and build your
   project.
3. Mistakes in your xml views could cause the R.java not to be
   generated. Go through your view files and make sure all the xml is
   right! Remove, if any import android.R;
4. Restart your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps in your other projects the classes referencing `R` are in the same package as `R`?

Comment: this must be a comment

Comment: How will his classes be in Gen folder??